# Switch statement automatically performing cases without meeting case requirements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I made this switch statement and it begun to work until i began adding more code to it.. take a look:

```
var txt;
var begin = 'Some text';
var briefBegin = 'Some text';
var started = false; 
var Input = function () {

    switch (true) {
    case 'start' && !started:
        txt = begin;
        started = true;
        break;

    case 'start brief' && !started:
        txt = bbegin;
        started = true;
        break;

    default:
        txt = "Some text."
    }
    $('.output1').text(txt);
};
```

I then called it down here...

```
var teext;
$(".submit").click(function() {
    teext = $('.inputt').val();
    Input(teext);
    console.log(teext);
});
$(".inputt").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $(".submit").click();
    }
});
```

So whenever i type something in the input field (under the class ".inputt") whether it fits the case or not, it automatically prints every case from top to bottom. Any help will be appreciated :D thanks

Comment: The function doesn't use its argument in any way.

Comment: Your `case`s don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want. It compares the parameter that it's given to the strings in the `case` statements.

```
var Input = function (text) {

    switch (true) {
    case text == 'start' && !started:
        txt = begin;
        started = true;
        break;

    case text == 'start brief' && !started:
        txt = bbegin;
        started = true;
        break;

    default:
        txt = "Some text."
    }
    $('.output1').text(txt);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'start' && !started:
```

The expression `'start' && !started` evaluates to `!started`, since `'start'` is always truthy.

`switch` blocks can only switch on the value of a single expression; your code cannot work.